# How to programmatically expand a PyCollapsiblePane in wxPython?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I use a **PyCollapsiblePane** to let the user hide or shox some information. In some case, I need this **PyCollapsiblePane** to be expanded by default (at the creation).

When I use the **Expand**, my problem is solved but the window is reduced to its minimum size.

How can I use this method without shrinking my window ?

I already try to use the **Layout** method of the object or of its parent but it doesn't work. Here is an example that show my problem:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.pycollapsiblepane as PCP

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "PyCollapsiblePane Demo")

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        title = wx.StaticText(panel, label="PyCollapsiblePane")
        title.SetFont(wx.Font(18, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD))
        title.SetForegroundColour("blue")

        self.cp = cp = PCP.PyCollapsiblePane(panel, label="Some Data",
                                             style=wx.CP_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.CP_NO_TLW_RESIZE)
        self.cp.Collapse(collapse=False)
        #self.open_pane()
        self.MakePaneContent(cp.GetPane())

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(title, 0, wx.ALL, 25)
        sizer.Add(cp, 0, wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 25)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Layout()


    def open_pane(self):
        self.cp.Collapse(collapse=False)
        # this change was generated by the user - send the event
        ev = wx.CollapsiblePaneEvent(self.cp, self.cp.GetId(), self.cp.IsCollapsed())
        self.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(ev)

    def MakePaneContent(self, pane):
        ''' Just makes a few controls to put on `PyCollapsiblePane`. '''

        nameLbl = wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "Name:")
        name = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "");

        addrLbl = wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "Address:")
        addr1 = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "");
        addr2 = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "");

        cstLbl = wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "City, State, Zip:")
        city  = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "", size=(150,-1));
        state = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "", size=(50,-1));
        zip   = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "", size=(70,-1));

        addrSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=5, vgap=5)
        addrSizer.AddGrowableCol(1)
        addrSizer.Add(nameLbl, 0,
                      wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        addrSizer.Add(name, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        addrSizer.Add(addrLbl, 0,
                      wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        addrSizer.Add(addr1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        addrSizer.Add((5,5))
        addrSizer.Add(addr2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        addrSizer.Add(cstLbl, 0,
                      wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)

        cstSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        cstSizer.Add(city, 1)
        cstSizer.Add(state, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        cstSizer.Add(zip)
        addrSizer.Add(cstSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        border = wx.BoxSizer()
        border.Add(addrSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        pane.SetSizer(border)


# our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual

app = wx.App(0)

frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally find a trick to avoid the problem. Instead of using a [**wx.lib.agw.pycollapsiblepane.PyCollapsiblePane**](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.pycollapsiblepane.html#module-wx.lib.agw.pycollapsiblepane), just use a [**wx.CollapsiblePane**](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.CollapsiblePane.html). Thanks to it, the code works fine and both can be use the same way. The only thing that changes is the way these objects are graphically represented.

Here is the fixed version of my code:

```py
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.pycollapsiblepane as PCP

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "PyCollapsiblePane Demo")

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        title = wx.StaticText(panel, label="PyCollapsiblePane")
        title.SetFont(wx.Font(18, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD))
        title.SetForegroundColour("blue")

        self.cp = cp = wx.CollapsiblePane(panel, label="Some Data",
                                             style=wx.CP_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.CP_NO_TLW_RESIZE)
        self.MakePaneContent(cp.GetPane())
        self.cp.Expand()

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(title, 0, wx.ALL, 25)
        sizer.Add(cp, 0, wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 25)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Layout()

    def MakePaneContent(self, pane):
        ''' Just makes a few controls to put on `PyCollapsiblePane`. '''

        nameLbl = wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "Name:")
        name = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "");

        addrLbl = wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "Address:")
        addr1 = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "");
        addr2 = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "");

        cstLbl = wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "City, State, Zip:")
        city  = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "", size=(150,-1));
        state = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "", size=(50,-1));
        zip   = wx.TextCtrl(pane, -1, "", size=(70,-1));

        addrSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=5, vgap=5)
        addrSizer.AddGrowableCol(1)
        addrSizer.Add(nameLbl, 0,
                      wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        addrSizer.Add(name, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        addrSizer.Add(addrLbl, 0,
                      wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        addrSizer.Add(addr1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        addrSizer.Add((5,5))
        addrSizer.Add(addr2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        addrSizer.Add(cstLbl, 0,
                      wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)

        cstSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        cstSizer.Add(city, 1)
        cstSizer.Add(state, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        cstSizer.Add(zip)
        addrSizer.Add(cstSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        border = wx.BoxSizer()
        border.Add(addrSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        pane.SetSizer(border)


# our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual

app = wx.App(0)

frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```